# Pull rows with only certain data in them PHP & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull information and display it in a table form on a php page i have a mysql DB i have something like below which list everything in the table but i would like to have it only show certain information if a certain data is present

Columns i would like to display on the page

```
object_id, Name and, wish.
```

but i only want rows from the DB to be displayed if a column

```
wishState is ("pending")
```

this is what i have scoured around to find so far wich brings everything in.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE";
$results = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $field) {
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Thanks Ryan

Comment: you should mysqli_* functions. Mysql is depracated and will no longer be supported in the future.

Comment: See my answer it solves your question using mysqli for added security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire ext/mysql PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is **officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0** and will be removed in the future. So please don't use **mysql_*** anymore.

```
//selects data where wish is pending 
$query="SELECT * FROM `MY_TABLE` WHERE `wish`='pending'";
$results = mysqli_query($your_db_connection, $query) or exit(mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

//show only object_id, name and wish
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['object_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['wish']. '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE `wish`='pending'";
```

That should work based on the information you gave us. WHERE tells the database to search for rows WHERE the column WISH is equal to "pending".

Comment: thank you so if the table actually shows ("pending") i could just put in '("pending")' ?

Comment: It should if its exactly the same